# SQL Server 2008 Express: How do you remove a Database Engine instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-express

I tried upgrading SQL Server Express 2008 to SP1, but the Setup was very far from clear. I ended up with 2 database engines.

I now want to install Management Studio Express, but it apparently means I have to create yet another database engine.

How do I remove these existing ones? I want to name it SqlExpress but I can't because it already exists.

[image]

When installing, I have to select "Perform a new installation...", otherwise I won't be able to see "Management Tool - Basic".

[image]

And I don't see Database Engine selection

[image]

Add/Remove Programs screenshot:
[image]

Thank you for your replies!

Comment: You don't need to install another instance when installing management studio. When you get to the component selection screen, only select management tools, uncheck database engine.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but it's not there, I updated the question with more screenshots, thanks!

Comment: if it's not listed there then the installer does not contain the database engine, so it won't install another instance.

Comment: But it just created another instance (of whatever it's called if it's not database engine). Please see my screenshots. And thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have an instance installed on the "Installation Type" screen select Add components to an existing instance.

To remove the second instance, you need to go into add/remove programs and run through the wizard to remove an instance.

Comment: Thanks! The same wizard as for the installation? I tried that, there is no option to remove it.

Comment: To remove an instance go into add remove programs and run through the removal process from there.

Comment: Thanks but... what do you mean by "run through the removal process from there"...? I have put a screenshot of what I see in Add/Remove Programs, I cannot see the SQL Server instance there.

Comment: Use the one labeled "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (64-bit)"

Comment: Selecting the (64-bit) version also fixed this issue for me on SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the SQL Server Management Studio Express (stand-alone) installtion from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8961

Uninstall your second SQLExpress instance using Add/Remove programs

Comment: It is not in Add/Remove Programs, I'll post the screenshot now to the question.

Comment: Btw that download link is for 2005, do you have one for 2008 that is standalone? And thanks btw!